# How to do interpolation in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, typescript, interpolation

I have 2 components in my Angular project. Component A sends an id in this way:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/numbersbyareacode', element.id]">
   {{element.title}} 
</a>
```

Component B will be displayed now and gets the id. The id is saved to the local variable id as you can see in the ts class of Component B. When I print id to the console, it will show the given id.

Component B:

```
id: any;

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private httpClient: HttpClient) {
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
  console.log(this.id);
  this.getAllNumbersByAreacode();
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
}

getAllNumbersByAreacode() {
    // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
    this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:8080/p/api/v1/phonenumbers/
    getN/${id}').subscribe((res: any[]) => {         //this interpolation doesn't work
      console.log(res);
    });
}
```

I am trying to add the id to the path but I am doing something wrong, cause I get an error with that path shown like this in the console:

```
"http://localhost:8080/p/api/v1/phonenumbers/getN/$%7Bid%7D"...
```

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to change this ('') to this (``)

Because (') behaves like a normal string while (`) behaves like some sort of "smart" string and it's called template literals

```
this.httpClient.get(`http://localhost:8080/p/api/v1/phonenumbers/getN/${id}`)
```

When (') is used you need to connect it together using `+`

```
this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:8080/p/api/v1/phonenumbers/getN/' + id)
```

Comment: I marked this as the right answer because it is more detailed.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't actually have anything to do with Angular, it's just about javascript. Template literals are written using backticks https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

So you should use backticks (`) instead of single quotes (')

```
this.httpClient.get(`http://localhost:8080/p/api/v1/phonenumbers/getN/${id}`)
    .subscribe((res: any[]) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
```

Comment: Crazy, now it is doing its work! Thanks man!